# Getting tor nodes list

Tags: source-code, research

I'm modifying tor source code for research purposes and I want to modify concept of getting tor nodes list. Now, tor client is getting tor nodes from directory servers and I want to change it.

My question is, where can I find piece of code where this process is done? My current version of tor is 0.4.5.6 cloned from git repository.

Answer (score 0):

Three important files you'll want to look at are:

- `feature/dirclient/dirclient.c`
- `feature/nodelist/networkstatus.c`
- `feature/nodelist/routerlist.c`

You might want to start at `fetch_networkstatus_callback()` which is the callback triggered by the eventloop to download new directory documents. Without knowing more about what you want to do, I can't suggest specific parts of the code to look at.

Comment: I want to build new system of getting nodes. Nowadays, clients are getting tor nodes only from directory servers. I want to build blockchain protocol to distribute available tor nodes with consensus protocol.

Comment: Okay, the existing network status code isn't very flexible, so you'll probably want to re-write a lot of the existing network status code.

Comment: Method `fetch_networkstatus_callback()` is periodically invoking, and is also invoking when new client wants to join tor network and create circuit?

Comment: That function is run once per second when tor is bootstrapping. Other than on a HUP signal, I'm not sure if there are any other places that trigger a directory download.

Comment: And where I can find these downloaded relays from directory authorities?

Comment: Do you mean where are they stored on disc? They're in `DataDirectory` (typically `/var/lib/tor`) in the `cached-microdesc-consensus` and `cached-microdescs` files.

Comment: I mean where they are stored like in data structures when app is running.